# Collect all public posts in facebook using graph api

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am trying to collect all public posts from facebook using Graph api like twitter streaming.But i couldn't find out a way, i checked the graph api search function
https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=anyword

it needs a parameter or keyword for search, but i need all the public posts not specific to any keyword or any user or any page. Please help me to find out this.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to perform such a vague search. Any type of search query require at least one parameter / criteria to be search. Even if had been possible, it would be like receivind millions of arrays in a single objects(which is practically impossible)

In your case it should be all the posts from a single user, a group or a page. You can receive real-time updates from the Graph API, but that too needs the object to be subscribed to other objects. Check the following link.
[Real Time Updates](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/realtime/)